# convert pandas multiindex series to Json python

Tags: python, json, pandas

Hi I have two pandas series similar to below

PnL

```
           Product Name      Price
Company A  Orange            3000
Company B  Apple             2000
           Grapes            1000
```

Tax

```
           Product Name      Price
Company A  Orange            100
Company B  Apple             100
           Grapes            10
```

I would like to transform the pandas series into the following JSON format

```
{'PnL':{'Company A':{'productName':'Orange','price':3000},
        'Company B':[{'productName':'Apple','price':2000},
                     {'productName':'Grapes','price':1000}]
       },
 'Tax':{'Company A':{'productName':'Orange','price':100},
        'Company B':[{'productName':'Apple','price':100},
                     {'productName':'Grapes','price':10}]
       }
}
```

I have tried to use the code below

```
convertedJson = json.dumps([{'company': k[0], 'productName':k[1],'price': v} for k,v in df.items()])
```

but I cannot form the JSON which I want to produce.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Use the `to_json` function - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I have tried with to_json(orient="index") but it cannot produce what I want

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for join `DaatFrame`s together and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for expected output:

```
df = pd.concat([s1, s2], keys=('PnL','Tax')).reset_index()
df.columns = ['type','company','productName','price']
print (df)
  type    company productName  price
0  PnL  Company A      Orange   3000
1  PnL  Company B       Apple   2000
2  PnL  Company B      Grapes   1000
3  Tax  Company A      Orange   3000
4  Tax  Company B       Apple   2000
5  Tax  Company B      Grapes   1000

d = (df.groupby(['type','company'])['productName','price']
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='data')
       .groupby('type')['company','data']
       .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('company')['data'].to_dict())
       .to_json()
       )
```

---

```
print (d)

{
    "PnL": {
        "Company A": [{
            "productName": "Orange",
            "price": 3000
        }],
        "Company B": [{
            "productName": "Apple",
            "price": 2000
        }, {
            "productName": "Grapes",
            "price": 1000
        }]
    },
    "Tax": {
        "Company A": [{
            "productName": "Orange",
            "price": 3000
        }],
        "Company B": [{
            "productName": "Apple",
            "price": 2000
        }, {
            "productName": "Grapes",
            "price": 1000
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the line ```reset_index(name='data')``` @jezrael