# Convert a table with subset to a Json format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, formatting

I am trying to process publicly listed companies financials. I have downloaded the data now I am trying to convert it to `JSON` format.

There are subsections in the table and used 4 ~'s to denote 1 indentation and 8 for 2 indentations as below:

- one indentation represents 1 level down
- double indentation represents 2 levels down

For example **`Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A`** is the section header and **`COGS Growth`** should be captured as a child element of **`Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A`**.

Can you please help me in identifying a way as to how to convert this dataframe to a `JSON` file?

**Table representing Data Frame**

```
|                                       Item  Item|      2016|     2017 |    2018 |    2019   |     2020 |  5-year trend|
|                                     :---------: |    :----:|   :----: |  :----: |  :----:   |   :----: |:------------:|
| Sales/Revenue                                   |-         |-         |-        | -         |615.82K   | NaN          |
| ~~~~Sales Growth                                |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
| Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A             |684       |5.44K     |3.14K    | 32.5K     |-         | NaN          |
| ~~~~COGS Growth                                 |-         |694.59%   |-42.19%  | 934.31%   |-         | NaN          |
| ~~~~COGS excluding D&A                          |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
| ~~~~Depreciation & Amortization Expense         |684       |5.44K     |3.14K    | 32.5K     |41.83K    | NaN          |
| ~~~~~~~~Depreciation                            |684       |5.44K     |3.14K    | 32.5K     |41.83K    | NaN          |
| ~~~~~~~~Amortization of Intangibles             |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
| Gross Income                                    |(684)     |(5.44K)   |(3.14K)  | (32.5K)   |-         | NaN          |
| ~~~~Gross Income Growth                         |-         |-694.59%  |42.19%   | -934.31%  |-         | NaN          |
| ~~~~Gross Profit Margin                         |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
| SG&A Expense                                    |1.91M     |4.79M     |5.88M    | 9.5M      |9.63M     | NaN          |
| ~~~~SGA Growth                                  |-         |151.12%   |22.61%   | 61.51%    |1.37%     | NaN          |
| ~~~~Research & Development                      |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
| ~~~~Other SG&A                                  |1.91M     |4.79M     |5.88M    | 9.5M      |9.63M     | NaN          |
| ~~~~Other Operating Expense                     |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
| Unusual Expense                                 |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
| EBIT after Unusual Expense                      |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
| Non Operating Income/Expense                    |-         |-         |(52.76K) | 60.09K    |(2.2K)    | NaN          |
| Non-Operating Interest Income                   |8.9K      |170.93K   |59.8K    | 50.79K    |19.15K    | NaN          |
| Equity in Affiliates (Pretax)                   |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
| Interest Expense                                |-         |-         |-        | -         |115.55K   | NaN          |
| ~~~~Interest Expense Growth                     |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
| ~~~~Gross Interest Expense                      |-         |-         |-        | -         |115.55K   | NaN          |
| ~~~~Interest Capitalized                        |-         |-         |-        | -         |-         | NaN          |
```

**Table Organized in subsections**

| Item Item | Subsection1 | Subsection2 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 5-year trend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sales/Revenue |  |  | - | - | - | - | 615.82K | NaN |
|  | Sales Growth |  | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |
| Cost of Goods Sold (COGS) incl. D&A |  |  | 684 | 5.44K | 3.14K | 32.5K | - | NaN |
|  | COGS Growth |  | - | 694.59% | -42.19% | 934.31% | - | NaN |
|  | COGS excluding D&A |  | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |
|  | Depreciation & Amortization Expense |  | 684 | 5.44K | 3.14K | 32.5K | 41.83K | NaN |
|  |  | Depreciation | 684 | 5.44K | 3.14K | 32.5K | 41.83K | NaN |
|  |  | Amortization of Intangibles | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |
| Gross Income |  |  | (684) | (5.44K) | (3.14K) | (32.5K) | - | NaN |
|  | Gross Income Growth |  | - | -694.59% | 42.19% | -934.31% | - | NaN |
|  | Gross Profit Mar |  | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |
| SG&A Expense |  |  | 1.91M | 4.79M | 5.88M | 9.5M | 9.63M | NaN |
|  | SGA Growth |  | - | 151.12% | 22.61% | 61.51% | 1.37% | NaN |
|  | Research & Development |  | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |
|  | Other SG&A |  | 1.91M | 4.79M | 5.88M | 9.5M | 9.63M | NaN |
|  | Other Operating Expense |  | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |
| Unusual Expense |  |  | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |
| EBIT after Unusual Expense |  |  | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |
| Non Operating Income/Expense |  |  | - | - | (52.76K) | 60.09K | (2.2K) | NaN |
| Non-Operating Interest Income |  |  | 8.9K | 170.93K | 59.8K | 50.79K | 19.15K | NaN |
| Equity in Affiliates (Pretax) |  |  | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |
| Interest Expense |  |  | - | - | - | - | 115.55K | NaN |
|  | Interest Expense Growth |  | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |
|  | Gross Interest Expense |  | - | - | - | - | 115.55K | NaN |
|  | Interest Capitalized |  | - | - | - | - | - | NaN |

Comment: What is meant by the table representing the dataframe?
What is that file actually?

Comment: It's depicting the data held in the dataframe in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this by adding values to the missing cells and then groupby on 3 columns the code looks like below.  Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52923685/convert-pandas-multiindex-series-to-json-python) I used to build this code

```
d = (dframe.fillna("-").groupby(['Item  Item','ItemSubsection1','ItemSubsection2'])['2016','2017','2018','2019','2020']
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='data')
       .groupby(['Item  Item','ItemSubsection1'])['ItemSubsection2','data']
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
       .reset_index(name='data')
       .groupby('Item  Item')['ItemSubsection1','data']
       .apply(lambda x: x.set_index('ItemSubsection1', 'ItemSubsection2')['data'].to_dict())
       .to_json()
       )
```